# Have a name/value collection, want to write it out to a file

Tags: python

I have a name/value collection like this:

```
for k,v in sorted(userlist):
    print k, v
```

How can I write this out to a file, having each key on a single line, and I want it to overright anything if the file exists.

I will then modify the file by hand, and then I want to read the file back into the dictionary.

sorry new to this kinda.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look a http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files this should give you a quick insight in to how to read and write files in python

Here is for writing the file :

```
f = open('/tmp/workfile', 'w')
delimiter = ' '
for k,v in sorted(list):
  f.write(k +delimiter+ v)
```

Here is for reading the file :

```
f = open('/tmp/workfile')
map = {}
while f:
  r = f.readline().split()
  map[r[0]]=r[1]
```

Comment: getting an error 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable' at the line map[r[0]] = r[1]

Comment: should be split() instead of split

Answer (score 2):

How do you want it formatted?  I'll let you decide on formatting

```
with open( filename, 'w' ) as file:
    def write_to_file( (key, value) ):
        #put your formatting down below
        file.write( str( key ) + ", " + str( value ) )

    map( write_to_file, sorted( userlist ) )
```

original answer didn't close file.

Here's taking what you had:

```
with open( filename, 'w' ) as file:
    for k,v in sorted( userlist ):
        file.write( str( k ) + ", " + str( v ) )
```

Comment: I guess I have to add a new line?

Comment: @Blankman pretty much.  You could just add the with clause above your for loop and all the other formatting stuff below it.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
import json

read = json.load
write = lambda file, obj : json.dump(obj, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unknown that [**pickle**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)  output *often is easy to alter by hand*.  Probably becaues a lot of other serializing tools don't have a file format that allows that, but also out of safety reasons (see remark after example)

An example :

```
#import pickle
mydict = {}
mydict[0] = "100";
mydict[1] = "1000";
file = open('example.txt','w')
pickle.dump(mydict,f)
```

Afterwards I will change the textvalue directly in the texfile : ('10' becomes '99' and '100' becomes '999'

```
(dp0
I0
S'99'
p1
sI1
S'999'
p2
s.
```

Than, we load the file again and display the resuts :

```
f = open('example.txt','r')
mydict = pickle.load(f)
print mydict
```

and we indeed get the altered output :

```
{0: '99', 1: '999'}
```

I have tried this succesfully with lots of datatypes and in files with over a million lines.

But a **warning** : **changing the filestructure can cause it to become unreadable for pickle**

So it's ok to do this as long you backup your serialized data first.